# Test statistic to assess the of spatial structure of clusters

Tags: clustering, spatial

I have a series of $n$ observations $i_{1},i_{2},..,i_{n}$, approximately spread across 10 different regions. Each $i$ has an associated $X$ and $Y$ coordinate value in 2-D Cartesian space. Each $i$ also has an associated cluster, where the number of clusters within a region is greater than one and less than $n$. I would like to compare the regions in terms how how strongly the clusters are structured in the 2-D Cartesian space. By 'structures' I suppose I a metric that is high when all the points in a given cluster show low dispersion around the mean relative to the total dispersion across all points.

What is a test statistic I can use?

There are some examples below:

This is an example of a region showing strong spatial structure of the clusters (denoted by the colour). I.e.,
[image]

This is an example of a region showing weak/no spatial clustering.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

[K-Means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) clustering uses within-cluster variances (squared pairwise Euclidean distances), and that's probably a very good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have observations spread across different regions and you're interested in the structure of clusters within these regions, K-Means may not be the best fit if the clusters are not spherical or have varying sizes and densities. Algorithms that do not assume spherical clusters and can handle different densities, such as DBSCAN or Gaussian Mixture Models, might be more appropriate.

For comparing the structure of clusters, regardless of the clustering algorithm used, metrics such as the [Silhouette Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)), [Calinski-Harabasz Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calinski%E2%80%93Harabasz_index), and the [Davies-Bouldin Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davies%E2%80%93Bouldin_index) can help with understanding the compactness and separation of the clusters.

Beyond these metrics, a statistical approach could involve a comparison of variances such as classical ANOVA, MANOVA and spatial autocorrelation models. For the interest in dispersion, you could look a within-cluster dispersion (ie. a metric like the average distance from each point in a cluster to the centroid of that cluster); between-cluster edispersion (involving the calculating the distance between cluster centroids or other representative points); ratio of between- to within-cluster dispersion which can serve as a bespoke metric for this requirement indicating the degree to which clusters are separated from each other compared to how spread out they are internally.